# tf.data.Dataset input pipeline delivering bad results compared to Threading/Queue

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Earlier I used Threads and Queues as my Data Pipeline and I got a really high Util on both GPUs (the data was created on the fly). I wanted to use the tf Dataset, but I struggle to reproduce the results.

I tried a lot of approches. Since I create data on the fly the from_generator() method seemed perfect. The code you see below is my last try I did. It seems that there is a bottleneck in creating the data although I am using the map() function for the processing of the generated images. What I tried in the code below I wanted to "multithread" the generators somehow, so there is more data coming in at the same time. But no better results so far.

```
def generator(n):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        while True:
            ...
            yield image, label

def get_generator(n):
    return partial(generator, n)

def dataset(n):
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(get_generator(n), output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None,None,1]),tf.TensorShape([None,None,1])))

def input_fn():
# ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None,None,1]),tf.TensorShape([None,None,1])))
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(BATCH_SIZE).apply(tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(dataset, cycle_length=BATCH_SIZE))
    ds = ds.map(map_func=lambda img, lbl: processImage(img, lbl))
    ds = ds.shuffle(SHUFFLE_SIZE)
    ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    ds = ds.prefetch(1)
return ds
```

The expected results would be a high GPU Util (>80%), but for now it is really low 10/20%.

Comment: Why do you need from_generator? It has some limitations, inherited from py_func
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator

Comment: @Sharky because I thought since I am generating data on the fly that would be perfect. though another workaround would be to put the data I am generating from thredas into a dataset if that works somehow. so I could use a hybrid of the old architecture and the Dataset API

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your data is images. Just try from_tensor_slices.

Comment: @Sharky but then I would have to have my images already generated right?

Comment: No, you can control it with shuffle buffer size. Images will be loaded when you call iterator. Besides you can add prefetch op, and specify number of batches being produced in parallel. Take a look.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: Hello, I have [blank code](https://github.com/Red-Eyed/dnn_models/blob/master/dataset/keras_dataset.py) for this. It utilises >80% It runs on MNIST and CIFAR, but I also use it on my big private image dataset.

Comment: Also, u can use cache. It speedups significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` instead.
Just pass image/labels path. The function accepts filenames as argument.

```
def input_func():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images_path, labels_path)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle().repeat()
    ...
    return dataset
```

Comment: Sorry, there is no path for my images since they are generated and taken from the queue the same time the training is running...

Comment: @craft How and where are your images stored?

Comment: They are just stored as jpgs and loaded into the memory before the training. When the training starts I put preprocess them, put them into a queue and so on

Comment: Then just try what I suggested. No need to use queue at all.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah maybe you are right. I will try it out tommorow.

Comment: Actually I managed to see that when starting the training my GPUs are not recognized. See my other thread.